# Boost asio socket multicast to a specific ethernet interface

Tags: boost, interface, boost-asio, multicast

I thought I had found the answer in the following example, but not quite.

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service); 
...
boost::asio::ip::address_v4 local_interface =
    boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("1.2.3.4");
boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface option(local_interface);
socket.set_option(option);
```

How do I map `eth0` to the appropriate outbound_interface option?

Comment: Might wanna check the formatting on your post there...

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine on Windows and Mac OS X:

```
    const ip::udp::resolver::query queryIF( ip::udp::v4(),                   
                                        _description->getInterface(), "0" ); 
    const ip::udp::resolver::iterator interfaceIP =                          
        resolver.resolve( queryIF );                                         

    if( interfaceIP == end )                                                 
        return false;                                                        

    const ip::address ifAddr( ip::udp::endpoint( *interfaceIP ).address( )); 

    _read->set_option( ip::multicast::join_group( mcAddr.to_v4(),            
                                                  ifAddr.to_v4( )));         
    _write->set_option( ip::multicast::outbound_interface( ifAddr.to_v4()));
```

EDIT: I had some issues on Linux, but did not look into it yet. My guess is the socket option is ignored in favor of the routing table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why your example and eile's example don't work is because you didn't set the SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option.

See this to know why it doesn't work: http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/10/code-snippet-sobindtodevice.html

See this to know how to do it with boost::asio: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2724

Comment: Link is broken now, which renders this answer nearly useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**************************************************************************//**
\brief      
\details    
*******************************************************************************/
class UDPClient : public BoostSocketClient
{
public:
    UDPClient ();
    virtual ~UDPClient();
    virtual ARLErrorCode_e open(int port_num, const char* network_type="ipv4", const char* ip_address="", uint32_t listen_interface=0);
    virtual ARLErrorCode_e send(u8* message, u32 size);
    virtual ARLErrorCode_e close();
    virtual bool isOpen();
    //virtual void onReceived(u8*, u32);

private:
    void startReceive();
    void handleReceive(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t);
    void handleSend(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

private:
    boost::asio::io_service send_ios_;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> send_worker_;

    boost::asio::io_service receive_ios_;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> receive_worker_;

    boost::thread send_thread_;
    boost::thread receive_thread_;
    boost::array<u8, 1024> _buffer;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint send_endpoint_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint_;

    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> send_udp_socket_;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> receive_udp_socket_;

};


#include <ACCompLib/Include/Typedefs.h>
#include <ACCompLib/Include/ARLErrorCodes.h>
#include <NetLib/Platform/Boost/cpp/UDPClient.h>
#include "Ws2tcpip.h"
#include "Iphlpapi.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace asio;
using namespace ip;
using namespace NetLib;

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief          Constructor
\details        

*******************************************************************************/
UDPClient::UDPClient() 
{
    receive_worker_.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(receive_ios_));
}
/***************************************************************************//**
\brief          ctor
\details        
*******************************************************************************/
UDPClient::~UDPClient()
{
    try
    {
        receive_worker_.reset();
        //send_worker_.reset();
        if (send_thread_.joinable()) {
            send_thread_.join();
        }
        if (receive_thread_.joinable()) {
            receive_thread_.join();
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::string str = e.what();
    }
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief          
\details        
\note           
\param[in]      
*******************************************************************************/
ARLErrorCode_e UDPClient::open(int port_num, const char* network_type, const char* multicastAddress, uint32_t listen_interface)
{
    try
    {
        struct in_addr in;
        in.S_un.S_addr = listen_interface;
        char* address_listen = inet_ntoa(in);
        //const char* address_listen = "0.0.0.0";
        std::string address_mcast = multicastAddress;
        unsigned short address_port = port_num;

        boost::system::error_code ec;

        boost::asio::ip::address listen_addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(address_listen, ec);
        boost::asio::ip::address mcast_addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(address_mcast, ec);


        if (strcmp(network_type, "ipv4") == 0)
        {
            listen_endpoint_ = udp::endpoint(listen_addr, port_num);
            send_endpoint_ =  udp::endpoint(mcast_addr, port_num);
        }
        else if (strcmp(network_type, "ipv6") == 0)
        {
        }
        else
            return ES35_INVALID_SOCKET_CONNECTION;

        send_udp_socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(send_ios_));
        receive_udp_socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(receive_ios_));

        send_udp_socket_->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
        receive_udp_socket_->open(listen_endpoint_.protocol());
        send_udp_socket_->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        receive_udp_socket_->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));

        boost::asio::ip::address_v4 local_interface =
            boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(address_listen);
        boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface option(local_interface);


        // Join the multicast group.
        receive_udp_socket_->set_option(
            boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(mcast_addr));

        send_udp_socket_->set_option(option);
        receive_udp_socket_->set_option(option);

        boost::asio::ip::multicast::hops hops_option(3);
        //send_udp_socket_->set_option(hops_option);
        receive_udp_socket_->set_option(hops_option);

        receive_udp_socket_->bind(listen_endpoint_);


        startReceive();
        receive_thread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &receive_ios_));
        send_thread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &send_ios_));


        return ES_NoError;
    }
    catch (std::exception& exp)
    {
        std::string str = exp.what();
        return ES35_INVALID_SOCKET_CONNECTION;
    }
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief          
\details        
*******************************************************************************/
ARLErrorCode_e UDPClient::close(void)
{
    try {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        //udp_socket_->cancel();
        //udp_socket_.shutdown(socket_base::shutdown_both, ec);
        if (ec) 
        {
            return ES35_INVALID_SOCKET_CONNECTION;
        }
        if (send_udp_socket_->is_open()) 
        {
            send_udp_socket_->close();
        }
        if (receive_udp_socket_->is_open())
        {
            receive_udp_socket_->close();
        }

        receive_udp_socket_.reset();
        send_udp_socket_.reset();

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::string str = e.what();
        return ES35_INVALID_SOCKET_CONNECTION;
    }

    return ES_NoError;
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief          
\details        
*******************************************************************************/
bool UDPClient::isOpen()
{
    return send_udp_socket_->is_open() && receive_udp_socket_->is_open();
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief      Send a message.     
\details    The message is sent asynchronously. 
\param      message
\param      message size
*******************************************************************************/
ARLErrorCode_e UDPClient::send(u8* message, u32 size)
{
    if (!isOpen()) {
        return ES35_INVALID_SOCKET_CONNECTION;
    }

    std::string send_to_address = send_endpoint_.address().to_string();



    send_udp_socket_->set_option(asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(false));

    send_udp_socket_->async_send_to(
        buffer(message, size),
        send_endpoint_,
        bind(
            &UDPClient::handleSend,
            this,
            asio::placeholders::error,
            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));


    return ES_NoError;
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief      Do nothing.         
\details    This function has the required signature to be used as an
            asynchronous send completion handler.
\param      not used
\param      not used
*******************************************************************************/
void UDPClient::handleSend(const system::error_code& error, size_t)
{
    if (error) 
    {
        BoostSocketClient::onError(ES35_UDP_SEND_ERROR, (u8*)error.message().c_str(), error.message().size());
    }
    else
    {
        send_udp_socket_->set_option(asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
    }
}
/***************************************************************************//**
\brief  Start an asynchronous receiver.         
*******************************************************************************/
void NetLib::UDPClient::startReceive()
{

    receive_udp_socket_->async_receive_from(
        buffer(_buffer),
        sender_endpoint_,
        bind(
            &UDPClient::handleReceive,
            this,
            asio::placeholders::error,
            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    std::string sender_address = sender_endpoint_.address().to_string();
}

/***************************************************************************//**
\brief      Pass received data to the base class.   
\details    A new receiver is started.
\param      error code
\param      data size
*******************************************************************************/
void NetLib::UDPClient::handleReceive(const system::error_code& error, size_t size)
{
    if (!error || error == error::message_size)
    {
        BoostSocketClient::onReceived(_buffer.data(), size);

        startReceive();
    }
    else        
    {
        BoostSocketClient::onError(ES35_UDP_RECEIVE_ERROR, (u8*)error.message().c_str(), error.message().size());
    }
}


This code is not receiving response.please check
```

Comment: It would be much better answer if you included a short explanation as well as code.  That way it's not only solves the problem but also shows them how to do it and also why.  That way we all learn.

Answer (score 0):

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2724  is invalid.
The following code seems to be invalid:

```
boost::asio::ip::address_v4 local_interface = 
boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip);
boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface option(local_interface);
sock.set_option(option);
```

Comment: How to send data with a specific interface?? Boost Asio.